# Ssh to Google Cloud Storage from AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine

I am interested in knowing if it's possible to do ssh to google cloud storage from an AppEngine to read some file from there, process and insert data in BigQuery. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Neither Cloud Storage nor App Engine Standard have any concept of an "instance" that you could SSH to (unless you're using App Engine Flexible, but you still can't SSH to Cloud Storage).

However you can [talk to Cloud Storage from App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/setting-up-cloud-storage), or just directly [load your GCS bucket into BigQuery.](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data#introduction)